# Help with phrase: えらく[愉]{たの}しい[事]{こと}[続]{つづ}きなんだ

Tags: translation, meaning

I'm having trouble with the following: えらく愉しい事続きなんだ

I don't know the meaning of えらく as I've never seen that word before.

Comment: It's a form of the adjective えらい.

Comment: Try swapping えらく for すごく. Do you understand the meaning then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though this seems already answered, I decided to make it more complete.

"えらく" is a kind of adverb(副詞） that is used to emphasize on something.

Some examples I came up with...
 あの人は、えらく美人だ。
 えらく大きな会社だ。

But overall i don't think i hear this very often.
If you just want to emphasize, "すごく” or "とても”　would be a better choice.

Comment: How is "すごい” or "とても”  a better choice?

Comment: えらく can be replace by すごい often, but すごく can't be replaced by えらく all the time.

Comment: 1) A can be replaced by B often but B can't be replaced by A all the time, doesn't make B a better choice. 2) えらく is 連用形 of an i-adjective and とても is an adverb (i.e. they modify 用言) while すごい is the plain form of an i-adjective (i.e. modifies 体言). 3) "i don't think i hear this very often" →　Probably because this usage is pretty colloquial. You might not see/hear it in textbooks or formal conversation.